# Regional circulation and Cardiac output?

Tags: physiology, homework, cardiology

I am reading my study materials and think what is the systemic POV here

> **Regional circulation** Blood flow within the tissue/organs based on the functional demands of the tissue. 
>       E.g. The blood flow to the brain should remain relatively constant from a systemic POV (13% of CO at rest).

**What is the POV here?**

**Extension to the question and explanation.**
The last part is just 13% of maximal cardiac output.

Comment: I'd guess venous P[O_2], maybe. Who gives abbreviations without a key? Although the suggestion of "point of view" make sense in context.

Comment: Use the homework tag?

Comment: Given the answer this is more of an English Language question than Biology so I'll close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an abbreviation commonly used outside of the field of biology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be as simple as 'point of view'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really sometimes get confused by the abbreviations used in my study materials.